# Return with assert and comma operator

Tags: c++, c++17

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp gives this as a possible implementation for `std::clamp`:

```
template<class T, class Compare>
constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi, Compare comp )
{
    return assert( !comp(hi, lo) ),
        comp(v, lo) ? lo : comp(hi, v) ? hi : v;
}
```

While I do understand how this works, putting the assert statement in the return seems rather strange to me; I would have written it as:

```
template<class T, class Compare>
constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi, Compare comp )
{
    assert( !comp(hi, lo) );
    return comp(v, lo) ? lo : comp(hi, v) ? hi : v;
}
```

Still, I'm guessing they chose their implementation for a reason; is there advantage of their version over "mine"?

Comment: I sometimes use the comma trick when I have a sequence of declarations, and some imperative step needs to be taken.  `A a = whatever; B b = (imperative(a), whatever_else(a)); C c = ...`.  That is to say, in C90 code, where we don't have mixed declarations and statements.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In C++11, `constexpr` functions could only have a single return statement (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)). The suggested implementation allows the function to be used in a C++11 compliant compiler.

C++14 removed this restriction, so your implementation is also valid in C++14 or later.

Disregarding this, the functions are exactly equivalent, and your one is definitely more readable.

Comment: Even when the `assert` is moved out of the `return` statement onto its own line, there is still only one `return` statement. So, wouldn't it also be compatible with C++11?

Comment: Not quite. C++11 requires `constexpr` functions to consist of only null statements (empty `;`), `static_assert`, `typedef` and `using` declarations, `using` directives and one return statement (per [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)). Other statements (like a separate `assert`) are not allowed.

Comment: Is assert required to be a valid *expression* even when NDEBUG == 1? Couldn't it expand empty making the statement not compile?

Comment: @ gigabytes, from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert, assert(..) statement will always expand to valid expression irrespective of NDEBUG is defined or not.